# TCPDF Large content displaying shows allowed memeory size exhausted error

Tags: php, html, mysql, tcpdf

I'm trying to print some html data which is constructed from a mysql query. if the query returns only a few rows then the pdf creation is fine. But when the query result increases it shows:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1121976320 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 80 bytes)

I don't want to increase the memory_size using **ini_set()** in my code because the query result can be increase in future. So is there any other way to print the pdf avoiding this error.?? I tried by querying part by part and outputting the content. but still failed. the code i tried is:

```
do{
            $Result = $myFunctions->getQueryResult();
            $pdf_data = generatePDF($Result);
            ob_clean();
            ob_start();
            $pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
            $pdf->initialize($system);

            $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
            $pdf->SetAuthor(PDF_AUTHOR);
            $pdf->SetTitle(PDF_TITLE);
            $pdf->SetSubject(PDF_SUBJECT);
            $pdf->SetKeywords(PDF_KEYWORDS);


            $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
            $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));


            $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);


            $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);


            $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);


            $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);


            $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
            $pdf->AddPage();

            $pdf->writeHTML($pdf_data['header'], true, false, false, false, '');
            $pdf->writeHTML($pdf_data['table'], true, false, false, false, '');
           ob_end_flush();
            $page++;
        }while($page <= $totalPages);


        $pdf->Output("filename.pdf", 'I');

        exit;
```